# Convert List<XFile> to File in Dart / Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I pick a picture using this library `image_picker: 0.8.4+4`. Then the image saved into List..

After that i want to show the image in next page and make it ready to edit using this library `image_painter: 0.4.4+1`.

```
ImagePainter.file(
        // Need file,
        key: _imageKey,
        scalable: true,
        initialStrokeWidth: 2,
        initialColor: Colors.green,
        initialPaintMode: PaintMode.line,
      ),
```

Actually i just need how to convert `List<XFile>` to `File`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it:

[XFile](https://pub.dev/documentation/cross_file/latest/cross_file/XFile-class.html) has a property called `path` so the you can:

```dart
XFile xfile = ...;

File file = File(xfile.path);
```

If you have a list, you can use `map` or other way you prefer to create `File` using the `path` of a `XFile`.